# JSON Response from VB .NET ASPX Page

Tags: web-services, rest

I know there might be close answers around but I needed help on specific matter.

I have to create a web service that has to accept a URI like below:

serverip/?userID=15068866&serviceID=595&username=222&password=333&message=something

The response should also be in JSON format and the Service SHOULD be RESTful.

Since there is logic behind this service that has been developed by VB .NET, I have to develop this bit using VB .Net too.

If anyone can suggest a very basic tutorial (FOR VB .NET PLEASE NOT C#) or put me in a right direction that would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic tutorial in VB.NET which may be helpful to you:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/06/21/wcnet_configure-wcf-for-rest-with-json.aspx